# Meaning of selected object outline in 3D view

Tags: 3d-view, color, collections, select

I was trying new Collections feature in Blender 2.8 and somehow can't get consistent understanding what do outline colors of selected objects mean.

Here is my scene setup:

- created three "asset" objects (cube, icosphere and Suzzanne)
- created several groups and linked assets into them in various combinations (AB, AC, BC, ABC)
- added instances of groups to the scene (under Main collection)

Now when I select "pure" assets, everything is clear: active object is highlighted in light orange, co-selected objects - in dark orange.
[image: Scene setup and selected "pure" objects]

But when I select group instances, interesting things happen.

For the first group (AB) it highlights instance position "dummy" and the objects themselves (which is quite logical). Strange that it also highlights objects inside other groups, but it might be by design. 
[image: Selected AB instance]

For the second (AC) and third (BC) groups it highlights nothing except position "dummy".
[image: Selected AC group]

Finally for the fourth group (ABC) it highlights position and only Suzanne.
[image: Selected ABC group]

Also you can notice that highlights in wireframe and solid modes also differ.

Could you, please, clarify what is the logic behind such highlighting.

Thanks!

- Version: blender-2.80-fc182e318988-linux-glibc224-x86_64
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04